# Scala Implicits compilation error

Tags: scala

I wrote this code

```
case class Foo(x: Int)
case class Bar(y: Int)
object Foo {
    implicit def toBar(f: Foo) : Bar = { Bar(f.x) }
    implicit def toBarList(fl: List[Foo]) : List[Bar] = {fl.map{x: Bar => x}}
```

The toBarList function doesn't compile.

```
<console>:17: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Bar => Bar
 required: Foo => ?
       implicit def toBarList(fl : List[Foo]) : List[Bar] = { fl.map{x : Bar => x}}
```

However shouldn't the implicits system kick in here? meaning that compiler should detect that there is an error that the function expects a Bar but I am passing a Foo. Now there is already a implicit function in scope which converts Foo to a Bar, so that should be used and things should work.

So why did this not compile?

Comment: In first snippet, `{fl.map{x: Bar => b}}`, probably you meant `{fl.map{x: Bar => x}}` or `{fl.map{b: Bar => b}}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`map` is an ordinary method that takes a function argument, and `map` on a `List[Foo]` requires a function from `Foo`. You've provided an function from `Bar`—specifically `Bar => Bar`—but having an implicit conversion from `Foo` to `Bar` doesn't mean you have one from `Bar => Bar` to `Foo => Bar` (which is what the method needs).

If you want this to work you'll either need to provide a function from `Foo` and then apply the conversion (either explicitly or implicitly), or you'll need to provide an implicit conversion from `Bar => Bar` to `Foo => Bar` (similar to the one you're trying to provide from `List[Foo]` to `List[Bar]`, but with the conversion happening in the other direction, since `Function1` is contravariant in its first argument while `List` is covariant).

(This is all a very bad idea, though.)

Comment: pardon my ignorance. but when the compiler found that I have provided Foo => Bar but it needed Bar => Bar. Why didn't it look for an implicit and automagically put the Foo to Bar conversion there? therefore the compiler should convert my Foo => Bar conversion to Bar => Bar conversion because I have a Foo => Bar conversion in scope.

Comment: @KnowsNotMuch The core of the reason is that functions are just instances of a particular class (that happens to have some special syntax). There's no special-casing in this respect—if you need a `Foo => Bar` and have a `Bar => Bar`, the `Foo`-to-`Bar` conversion won't help you (just like it won't help you if you have a `List[Foo]` and need a `List[Bar]`).